# black activity giving error android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Just downloaded **Android Studio 2.1.3**.Every time it gives

`error: cannot resolve symbol appcompatactivity,oncreate.Further it shows message "Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.`

> Could not download junit.jar (junit:junit:4.12)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)"
>       apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.prateek.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

Comment: If you aren't writing unit tests, you can get rid of the dependency in the app module's `build.gradle`. Whats 'black activity'?

Comment: post gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing that line:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```